# NSRangeException, but where?

Tags: ios, crash, ios8, stack-trace, nsrangeexception

I have an app, which users are reporting to crash at random times. All crashes have the same stack

```
0   CoreFoundation  TAGPBIvarClearUInt32 (in SPONTAN) + 11  
1   libobjc.A.dylib _mh_execute_header (in SPONTAN) + 15567 
2   CoreFoundation  TAGPBIvarClearSFixed64 (in SPONTAN) + 13    
3   Foundation  -[AdvancedPriceViewController newAP:] (in SPONTAN) (AdvancedPriceViewController.m:68) + 110325  
4   SPONTAN +[TrStart isJSONTrStart:] (in SPONTAN) + 77 
5   SPONTAN __65-[MintRequestWorker processPreviousLoggedRequestsAsyncWithBlock:]_block_invoke_2 (in SPONTAN) + 397 
6   SPONTAN __58-[FileRepository readLoggedExceptionsWithCompletionBlock:]_block_invoke (in SPONTAN) + 281  
7   libdispatch.dylib   _mh_execute_header (in SPONTAN) + 6195  
8   libdispatch.dylib   -[FirstViewController viewDidLoad] (in SPONTAN) (FirstViewController.m:56) + 84257  
9   libdispatch.dylib   -[FirstViewController viewDidAppear:] (in SPONTAN) (FirstViewController.m:80) + 84769   
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib _mh_execute_header (in SPONTAN) + 3027  
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib _mh_execute_header (in SPONTAN) + 2712
```

This may look fine, but when I look at level 3, 8 and 9, the code makes no sense anymore.

```
3   Foundation  -[AdvancedPriceViewController newAP:] (in SPONTAN) (AdvancedPriceViewController.m:68) + 110325  
Line 68: NSMutableArray *arrayOfIndexPaths = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

8   libdispatch.dylib   -[FirstViewController viewDidLoad] (in SPONTAN) (FirstViewController.m:56) + 84257  
Line 56: [[SelectCity titleLabel] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir" size:15]];

9   libdispatch.dylib   -[FirstViewController viewDidAppear:] (in SPONTAN) (FirstViewController.m:80) + 84769   
Line 80: NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
```

The error is a NSRangeException

```
*** -[__NSCFConstantString substringToIndex:]: Index 2147483647 out of bounds; string length 0
```

Can anyone tell me what's going on here?

Comment: By the way, It's only happening on the 4 and 4S.

Comment: Not convinced about that stacktrace.  If it's a range exception when why isn't it in a method that accepts a range?

Comment: Exactly. It's something is not quite right.

Comment: I think the stack is corrupted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search your source for usage of the selector `substringToIndex:`. I'm not familiar with the `AdvancedPriceViewController` class; if it's yours, you'll probably find a `substringToIndex:` in `[AdvancedPriceViewController newAP:]` where you've constructed an `NSRange` object with `-1`. When `-1` is converted to a `uint32`, it'll appear as `2147483647` or `MAX_INT`.

Comment: The AdvancedPriceViewController class ins mine, yes! The substringToIndex is not used in neither my code anywhere.

Comment: Then it definitely sounds like you're trying to desymbolicate the crash log with the wrong dsym file. Still, the exception that's thrown will be accurate, so search your source for `substringToIndex:` and make sure you're not ever trying to pass `-1`.

Comment: It ended up being a memory leak in the facebook SDK. Facebook was also the only Framework in my project using the substringToIndex function.